# NpgsqlDataReader return nothing

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, npgsql

I use Npgsql to work with postgreSQL in my asp.net project.

I got a problem - NpgSqlDataReader returns nothing:

```
        NpgsqlCommand comm = new NpgsqlCommand(command, dbConnect);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        NpgsqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        dt.Load(reader);
        return dt;
```

command string:

```
string command = "SELECT mark, wmi, add_cod, manufacturer, mark_owner, country_code, country, additional_info FROM wmi_table WHERE wmi = '" + wmi.ToUpper() + "'; ";
```

in debugging it is:

```
SELECT mark, wmi, add_cod, manufacturer, mark_owner, country_code, country, additional_info FROM wmi_table WHERE wmi = 'XTA';
```

So, this is correct string, i use it in query tool in pgAdmin and it returns correct row. 
Connection to database is stable (checked through pgAdmin while my app is stopped in debugging).

Also tried:

```
da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(command, dbConnect);
DataSet ds = new DataSet("dataSet");
da.Fill(ds, "dataSet");
return ds;
```

Doesn't work also. How can i fix it?

Comment: Side note: do not *hardcode* values `'" + wmi.ToUpper() + "'` but use *parameters*

Comment: You are not getting an exception.  Which means the database does not have the data (connected to wrong server or database in server) or the query is bad.  I always recommend testing the query in a vendor tool (like SQL Server Management Studio) to verify the syntax of the query before testing in c#.